# What's the difference between xml methods (XML transformation)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transformation, xmldocument

can anyone help me please?

I need to transform one XML document to another by using XSLT.

So I have the next simple code:

```
 var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load("input.xml");
    var xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    var styleSheetFullPath = "DefaultStyleSheet.xsl";
    xslTransform.Load(styleSheetFullPath);
```

Input xml document looks like the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Object>
      <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
      <Meta name="FILENAME" format="string" frate="" />
    </Object>
</Root>
```

I need to transform it to next XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root> 
    <Object> 
        <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
        <FILENAME/> 
    </Object>
</Root>
```

When I trying to use the next approach it works well. But I need first write document to file and after the transformation I need to reed it.

```
var fileName = "result.xml";
using (var myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, null))
{
       xslTransform.Transform(xmlDocument.CreateNavigator(), null, myWriter);
}
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);
```

But when I trying create XML document dynamically by using the next approach

```
        var xmlDocOutput = new XmlDocument();
        var xmlDocOutputDeclaration = xmlDocOutput.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        xmlDocOutput.AppendChild(xmlDocOutputDeclaration);
        using (var xmlWriter = xmlDocOutput.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            xslTransform.Transform(xmlDocument.CreateNavigator(), null, xmlWriter);
        }
```

I get the next output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root> 
    <Object> 
    <GUID>201110180954525010129</GUID>
        <FILENAME> </FILENAME> 
    </Object>
</Root>
```

**So what can I do to preserve white space in element content.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider to post samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. And try to present samples that make sense, the last "output" sample you have presented is not even well-formed XML as it has two start tags `<Root>` but no closing tag and a start tag `<Object>` but a closing tag `</MAObject>`. So whatever your XSLT does, it is not likely to produce that output.

Comment: Please show us the complete stylesheet code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Is the problem that there's a space between <FILENAME> and </FILENAME> in that last output file? Otherwise the given file and the output file are equivalent.

Comment: what do you mean by "So what can I do to preserve white space in element content." ? What's the problem with your whitespaces?

Comment: Let me guess: you want to have a self-contained tag (eg. <FILENAME />) when there is either nothing, or whitespace, as the contents? 
For whitespace tips, refer to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipwhitesp/index.html